# jQuery UI drop effect and box-sizing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, css

I'm trying to animate the toggling of a box with jQuery UI's `drop` effect. This box has `box-sizing: border-box` applied to it, which seems to be causing some issues with the effect.

When the box animates, its width and height decrease like it's losing its included padding.

HTML

```
<button>Toggle</button>
<div id="box">
    <p>Some content</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#box{
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: -100px;
    background: #ccc;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
     box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

JS

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("#box").toggle("drop", {direction: "up"}, 400); 
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MgGvd/).

If I remove the box-sizing, it animates just fine.

Does anyone know what the issue might be with this and how to get around it?

Comment: border-box doesn't seem to add any value visually.  why are you using it?

Comment: I'm going to be using a lot of percentage widths and heights and adding paddings to those would be a pain otherwise.

Comment: I have been having a similar problem with the ".show". It would appear that jquery is ignoring box-sizing until after it is finished with the effect.

Answer (score 0):

use animate instead.  I'm not sure why `toggle` isn't working but this does.

```
$("button").click(function(){
   $("#box").animate({
    opacity: 0.25,
    right: '+=50',
    height: 'toggle'
  }, 400);
});
```

well...you might have to tinker with it a bit but the bug you brought up is fixed.

EDIT: forgot to add a fiddle for an example http://jsfiddle.net/4PJ5Z/